# Почему данные с формы не отправляются на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Реализую чат, создаю окно регистрации, и необходимо чтобы данные с формы отправлялись на сервер, чтобы затем отправил на сторону клиента для отображения в списке клиентов. Но почему то данные с формы не приходят, в чем проблема?
Вот форма index.html

```
  <form class = "FORM" action="" method="post">
        <label>Username</label><br>
        <input type = "TEXT" class = "CHECK" autocomplete="off" name="Username">
        <button class="BTN" onclick="redirect()">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Вот сервер на express index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('./database/database'); // подключаемся к бд
const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({extended: false});
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const {Server} = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server);

const port = 3000;
let id = 0;
let users = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (request, response ) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    app.post("/", urlencodedParser, function (request, response) {
        if(!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
        console.log(request.body);
        //response.send(`${request.body.userName} - ${request.body.userAge}`);
    });
.....
```

Почему не приходят данные с формы на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

1. Дайте атрибуту формы action значение '/'. <form action='/' ...
2. Установите тип кнопки как submit. <button type='submit'...

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, все равно не выводит ничего, он даже не заходит в участок кода apt.post